# Перевод описания для встраиваемого значка пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Есть [строка](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16831) которая я так понял показывается здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, эта строка (с небольшими изменениями) уже имела перевод раньше. К сожалению, история для таких строк недоступна через traducir, но видна в transifex:

> [image: flair]

Цветом помечены различия и указан процент совпадения строк. Предлагаю т.о. по сути перевода изменений не вносить. Должно быть доступно в новой сборке. Текущая  rev 2021.9.2.40142

Comment: то есть перевод можно удалить по логике?

Comment: @Andrew какой перевод?

Comment: тот который я добавил в своем ответе, я просто так понял из вашего ответа что перевод для строки есть и будет доступен в новой сборке, а значит мой наверное не нужен?

Comment: @Andrew в traducir его не осталось, а здесь - по желанию.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил свой вариант перевода:

`What is it? It’s a piece of valuable flair™ you can place on any website to show off your user profile!` - [Что это? Это важный значок ™, который вы можете разместить на любом веб-сайте, чтобы продемонстрировать свой профиль пользователя!](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16831)

Comment: to show off  это скорее хвастаться, выпендриваться

Comment: ну выпендриваться мне кажется немного не то будет на этом ресурсе)) хвастаться тоже норм я думаю